# react-native How to judge if it is a directory？

Tags: android, react-native

```
    import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

    const dirs = await RNFS.readdir(RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/data');
    for (let i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
      // How to judge if it is a directory ?
      // fs.lstatSync(dirs[i]).isDirectory() // Similar to this effect
    }
```

How to judge if it is a directory ?

Similar to this effect： `fs.lstatSync(dirs[i]).isDirectory()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that might help, it is in the documentation as well.

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readdirdirpath-string-promisereaddiritem

```
componentWillMount() {
    RNFS.readDir(RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + '/data')
        .then((result) => {
            console.warn('result: ', result); // debug

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if(result[i].isDirectory()) {
                    // It is a directory
                } else if(result[i].isFile()) {
                    // It is a file
                } else {
                    // I don't know what it is
                }
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message, err.code);
        });
}
```